# Not fetching data soon enough with Pinia in Nuxt.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, async-await, nuxt.js, pinia

I am trying to fetch templates from my backend. I am using Nuxt.js and Pinia for state management. The problem I have is that on every reload of the page i don't see my templates. It is only when i change something in my code and save a file a couple of times (and don't reload the page) when the templates sometime show up. I believe this is because they don't arrive at the exact time the `getTemplates` getter is called, and I need to wait for it somehow. That is why i am checking with a `v-if` directive to see if the length of `templates` inside the state is `> 0` and only then try to show my templates, but that doesn't help.

Here is the code for my `templates-store.ts`

```
import { defineStore } from "pinia";

const useTemplateStore = defineStore("templates", {
    state: () => ({
        templates: [] as any[],
        totalTemplates: 0,
        selectedTemplate: null,
    }),
    actions: {
        async getTemplates(url: string) {
            try {
                const { data } = await useFetch(url);
                const flattenData = flattenObj(data.value);
                if(flattenData) {
                    this.templates = flattenData as any[];
                    this.totalTemplates = flattenData.meta.pagination.total;
                }
            } catch(err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
            
        },
        setSelectedTemplate(template: any) {
            this.selectedTemplate = template;
        }
    },
});

export default useTemplateStore;
```

The `flattenObj` function is drilling down to the actual response that I need, since the backend I am using `Strapi`, always wraps its response inside a data object.

I have a component that is responsible for displaying a list of these templates. Here is part of that code:

```html
<template>
    <div class="row mt-4">
        <div v-for="template in templates"
            :key="template.id"
            class="col col-12 col-md-6 col-xl-4 col-xxxl-3 mb-4"
            >
            <TemplatesListaTemplatesCard :template="template" />
        </div>
        <div class="text-center">
            <button
                class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary btn-subtle radius-sm"
                @click="showMore"
                >
            Show More
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import useTemplateStore from "~~/store/template-store";
import { onBeforeMount } from "vue";

const url = "http://localhost:1337/api/templates";
const { getTemplates, templates, totalTemplates } = useTemplateStore();

const isLoadingTemplates = computed(() => {
    return templates.length > 0;
});

onBeforeMount(async () => {
    await getTemplates(url.value);
});
</script>
```

Comment: What's the problem here? Does it work when you refresh the page / navigate to your page? Do you expect the templates to reload when updating your code and the hot-reload hits?

Comment: When something doesnt display on the page the way you expect but does when you cause a hot reload (saving a code change) it's usually a sign that the UI data is not reactive.  If you check the value of `templates` in your devtools is the value correct even if the UI doesn't reflect that?

Comment: It didn't load the templates when i navigated to my page, or reloaded. i removed the `onBeforeMount` function, and instead I invoked `getTemplates` right after destructuring everything from my `useTemplateStore()`. Now it works i guess. But isn't this supposed to happen inside some lifecycle method like beforeMount? why is it letting me do this